# Retaining Mouse Finger on b:hover Elements

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS on several elements:

```
b:hover{
background-color: whitesmoke;
padding: 30px;
}
```

However, when rendering in Firefox, etc. the mouse pointer is no longer indicating a "finger pointer."  Instead, it indicates and "points" using a cursor.  Is there a way using CSS to retain the usual "finger pointer?"

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cursor:pointer`

```css
.b {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 30px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cursor:ponter;`  property.

```
    b{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 30px;
    cursor:ponter;
    }
```

See other **examples** of various `cursor` property here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=alias